# I need help writing data from a html form to a text file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file, text

I Know someone has already answered this question, but for some reason it might have been deleted or removed because I can seem to find it anymore, thanks for any help provided **strong text**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function WriteToFile(passForm) {
    set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");     
    set s   = fso.CreateTextFile("<your Path>/filename.txt", True);
    var firstName = document.getElementById('FirstName');
    var lastName  = document.getElementById('lastName');
    s.writeline("First Name :" + FirstName);
    s.writeline("Last Name :" + lastName); 
    s.Close();
 }

<form onSubmit="WriteToFile(this)">
<label>Type your first name:</label>
<input type="text" name="FirstName" id="firstName" size="20">
 
<label>Type your last name: </abel>
<input type="text" name="LastName" id="lastName" size="20">
 
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with your code please.

Comment: @YLR this code is self explanatory.